# Getting error 'django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist'

Tags: django, django-authentication

A similar question has been asked before but after going through all of them I was not able to find any answer to fit my case.

I am using Django's built-in authentication system to authenticate and log in a user. The user uses a log in form on index form and is supposed to be then redirected to a different url.

However after I log in with a username and password that are both valid entries, I am not redirected to the next url as I should be, and I get this error:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

These are my import lines for authenticate, login, and then for User.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

But I don't think the problem is there.

It can't find the user but I don't know why that could be, because I am creating a username in the form and a password so it should be present.

Here is my login code:

```
def index(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Received POST")
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("FORM is Valid")
            # proceed with registration
            username, pwd = request.POST.get("username", None), request.POST.get("password", None)
            if not username or not pwd:
                print("nobody around here")
                return HttpResponse("Username or password not present")
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user:
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=pwd)
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username, username, pwd)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("dashboard")
        else:
            print("FORM is NOT VALID")
     
            template = loader.get_template('index.html')
            context = {
                'username': 'Ralf',
                'form': form,
            }
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
    else:
        # load the template file
        template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    
        context = {
           'username': 'Ralf',
            'form': LoginForm(),
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
```

EDIT: I tried using a try except block and now the page will not load the form:
Here is the code I used:

```
 if form.is_valid():
        print("FORM is Valid")
        # proceed with registration
        username, pwd = request.POST.get("username", None), request.POST.get("password", None)
        if not username or not pwd:
            print("nobody around here")
            return HttpResponse("Username or password not present")
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=pwd)
        except:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, username, pwd)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("dashboard")
```

Comment: `user = User.objects.get(username=username)` raises an exception if no such user exists, hence `if user` will never be found. You can wrap the `user = User.objects.get(username=username)` in a `try`-`except` block, and in case of the `except` create a user.

Comment: Hi Willem, I tried adding a try except block and just edited my question with the way I did it. Did I do it correctly? The index page/form is not loading at all now.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just deleted this line and it worked: user = authenticate(username=username, password=pwd). Do you know why?